# How to populate sequelize associations - EDITED

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use Sequelize for the first time but after hours of reading documentation, blogs and issues I am still quite confused and need some help to point me in the right path to understand how associations works.
This is what I have done:

**EDIT**: I remove from models the *associate* function because it works only with an [index.js like this](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js). I define the association directly in index.js before sync(). After that querying the sqlite schema confirm the field **UserId** is added to the table.

DB connection module:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = new Sequelize({
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: './nodeapp.db.sqlite'
});    
db
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    db.models.User.hasMany(db.models.Order);
    // db.models.Order.belongsTo(db.models.User); // THIS WORKS TOO
    db.sync();
    console.log('Database synchronized successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
module.exports = db;
```

User model definition:

```
const DataTypes = require('sequelize');
const db = require('./index');
const User = db.define('User', {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
   },
...
});
/* REMOVED
User.associate = (models) => {
  models.User.hasMany(models.Order);
};
*/
module.exports = User;
```

Order model definition:

```
const DataTypes = require('sequelize');
const db = require('./index');
const Order = db.define('Order', {
  order_num: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
...
});
/* REMOVED
Order.associate = (models) => {
  models.Order.belongsTo(models.User);
};
*/
module.exports = Order;
```

Router module:

```
router.post('/order',(req,res) => {
  Order
    .create(req.body.order)
    .then(order => {

      // HERE IS WHERE I'AM TRYING TO POPULATE THE RELATION WITH SET ...
      order.setUser(req.body.user).then((order) => {
        res.send(order);
      })          

  .catch(error => {
    res.send(error);
  });
});
```

All the CRUD operations are working correctly if I don't consider the relations. I can't figure it out how to populate the user reference in the order model, my questions are:

- Defining the association in the model only add the foreign key field?
- I have to manually populate the foreign key with id value or I can use user Object?

I need some help figuring out where I've gone wrong here because I know I am not doing something new.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to some comments and similar issues I finally make it working. At the moment I found my mistake it is useful [this piece of documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html).
My mistakes were in the definition of the db and probbly this is not the best solution but I'am working on it and any suggestion or best practice will be accepted.

**DB Connection module**

```
...
db
.authenticate()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  const User = require('./user');
  const Account = require('./account');
  const Order = require('./order');
  // At this point all models needed for associations are defined
  Account.belongsTo(User);
  Order.belongsTo(User);
  Order.belongsTo(Account);
  Order.belongsTo(Account, {as: 'Shipto'});
  Order.belongsTo(Account, {as: 'Billto'});
  db.sync();
  console.log('Database synchronized successfully.');
})
...
```

The model definition files remain the same.

**Router module**

```
router.post('/order',(req,res) => {
 db.models.Order
 .create(req.body.order)
 .then((order) => {
   order.setUser(req.body.order.UserId);
   order.setAccount(req.body.order.AccountId);
   order.setShipto(req.body.order.ShiptoId);
   order.setBillto(req.body.order.Billtoid);
   res.send(order);
 })
 .catch(error => {
   res.send(error);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You must declare a primary key  in your model definitions:

   ```
   const User = db.define('User', {
     id: {
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
       primaryKey: true,
       autoIncrement: true,
     },
     username: {
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
       allowNull: false,
       unique: true
      }
   });

   const Order = db.define('Order', {
     id: {
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
       primaryKey: true,
       autoIncrement: true,
     },
     userId: {
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
     },
     order_num: {
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
       allowNull: false,
       unique: true
     }
   });
   ```
2. You must include all fields, including primary and foreign keys, in your migration files.

   ```
   module.exports = {
     up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
       return queryInterface.createTable('orders', {
             id: {
               type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
               primaryKey: true,
               autoIncrement: true,
             },
             userId: {
               type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
             },
             order_num: {
               type: DataTypes.STRING,
               allowNull: false,
               unique: true
             }
       });
     },

     down: function(queryInterface) {
       ...
     }
   };
   ```
3. Keep in mind ORM operations are asyncronous. Consider using `asyc/await`:

   ```
   router.post('/order', async (req,res) => {
     Order
       .create(req.body.order)
       .then(order => {

         // you must fetch the user instance from req.user.id
         const userInstance = models.User.findByPk(req.user.id)

         // HERE IS WHERE I'AM TRYING TO POPULATE THE RELATION WITH SET ...
         await order.setUser(userInstance, {save: false});
         order.save();
         res.send(order);
       })
     .catch(error => {
       res.send(error);
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: **Point3** : I edit the router module in order to use a promise also for the setUser but an error raise : *SequelizeForeignKeiConstraintError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed*

Comment: **Point2** : Why I need migrations files to set model's relationships working?

Comment: **Point1** : Sequelize also defines by default the fields id (primary key), createdAt and updatedAt to every model (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/getting-started.html#modeling-a-table)

Comment: 1. Yes, my example of a model definition above is not complete. You must add `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, etc if you require those fields
2. Are you using migrations? If so, then your migration file must tell the database which columns are part of your table

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't expose my issue in a clearer way. I don't have problems in defining models. I don't whant to change the defaults fields. I don't use migrations for the moment. My focus is on Associations, how to define, how to set and how to get.

Comment: Ok. Are you using `.sync`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create association like this, I have these associations in my models and they are working fine.

so just change the associations from this

```
User.associate = (models) => {
  models.User.hasMany(models.Order);
};
```

to this,

```
User.associate = (models) => {
  User.hasMany(models.Order, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
};
```

Comment: I don't understand why I may use **user_id** as foreignkey filed when I don't use 
underscore option (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#underscored-option). I am now trying to use the default foreignkey (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#foreign-keys)

Comment: Yes, this is not mandatory to provide foreignkey in options if you have underscored tablename_id column in your associated table, but the source code you have provided in question doesn't have that column i.e, user_id in order model  that's why I have used foreignkey in options supplied to hasMany.